# MAC LOCALHOST - Apache waits 60 seconds before resolving localhost

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost, timeout

I recently set up my Macbook Pro M1 running Ventura with a localhost environment using Homebrew (Apache/PHP).  Everything with my site is local with the exception of a remote MySQL database.  I'm using localhost (http://localhost) as my URL.

I know the database is connecting, because when the page finally loads, I'm getting data from it.

The site takes forever to load, and several of the AJAX calls eventually timeout and fail, rendering the localhost pretty much useless.

No Apache errors.  No PHP errors.  No errors in the browser console.

I did however notice in the Network tab of the browser console that the localhost is taking 60 seconds before it even begins to load the page.  This makes sense as to why it is so slow and as to why the AJAX calls are failing (because those too are having to wait that full 60 seconds once they are initialized).  See attached screenshot.

What could be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s likely the local code does a query to the MySQL database before providing the page contents to the browser. This query seems to be awaiting a DNS timeout looking up the PTR of your address.

Reverse DNS queries can be generated a number of places.

### Locally

- The local apache server may have `%h` in the LogFormat (replace with %a if so) or have enabled `HostnameLookups` (disable it).
- The PHP code may use `[gethostbyaddr][1]`.

### Remotely

- The remote MySQL server may have `skip_name_resolve` which forces the server to resolve DNS names of clients, ask you MySQL database host to [disable reverse DNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/host-cache.html).

> To disable DNS host name lookups, start the server with the skip_name_resolve system variable enabled. In this case, the server uses only IP addresses and not host names to match connecting hosts to rows in the MySQL grant tables. Only accounts specified in those tables using IP addresses can be used. (A client may not be able to connect if no account exists that specifies the client IP address.)

- If you can not disable it on the MySQL server, have your ISP assign matching PTR and A/AAAA records for your IP address.

  For example, add to the DNS for example.com:

  ```
  client IN A 203.0.113.10
  ```

  Add to 113.0.203.in-addr.arpa:

  ```
  10 IN PTR client.example.com.
  ```

The basic workflow of a page load:

- The Client initiates a connect, the web server accepts.
- If the server is configured to look up names, do so now.
- The server code is now called to dynamically generate the code.
- If that code uses `gethostbyaddr`, the language asks the resolver to look up the name and return it.
- The code makes a SQL query, the database server accepts.
- If the database server is configured to look up names, do so now.

At any of those instances where the lookup is made, the name server performs these steps:

- First consult the cache, and if the information has not expired then return it.
- If the information has expired, has a recent failure, or is non-existent then look up the information from the Internet name servers.
- If the query doesn't promptly reply, replies with an error, or some invalid code; then wait and try again periodically.
- When the query times out (typically in 45 to 70 seconds), reply with non-existent domain and save the entry as invalid.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  My database is hosted in AWS RDS, unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to modify skip_name_resolve.  That option is marked as "non-modifiable" in the RDS console.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy replies!  I'm still a bit confused here.  This is for local development on a Mac Book.  Why would the ISP have to be involved?  Shouldn't my PHP code simply be able to call the RDS endpoint as long as the IP addresses where the request is coming from are allowed in the Security Group?  I mean it does, it just has this 60 second "hang time".  My local sql client connects just fine to the endpoint.

Comment: When your local server opens a socket to the AWS, that is not local. That is happening in PHP code right? On the local machine. The remote AWS server does not reply until the DNS query is returned OR cached already. Since it's not cached, AWS MySQL server does a query. The query returns "Non-Existent Domain" error or "No such name". It then tries again a couple times and times out after 60 seconds. At that point the MySQL server processes the query and replies with the result.

Comment: Put differently: your local PHP code doing the MySQL query must wait until the server timeout trying to look up your local machines internet IP’s reverse DNS name. It ultimately fails, logs the failure on AWS, then falls back to just IP. Then the MySQL server replies to you PHP code.

Comment: Thank you for the extended explanation!

Comment: So, amongst all of the frustration of seeing that AWS doesn't allow this skip_name_resolve to be modified, I didn't even notice that it is in fact set to 1 (by default) with my Aurora db instance.  So, if this is set to true, why is it still waiting that 60 seconds?

Comment: For that I’ll need more info from you. Either (both would be better), the code doing the query from AWS and any error logs from the sql server.

Comment: Thirdly, the Apache configuration for the site. It could also be doing dns lookups locally. The main reason I felt confident in the answer is that the symptoms are textbook dns lookup timeout.

Comment: @will I updated with several places (I could think off the top of my head) where the local server could be doing a DNS query. You could also attempt to run `tcpdump -n port 53` on all the active network interfaces of the machine to see DNS queries. This would confirm the theory.